# UITableViewCell show delete button on tap

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to achieve following:

1. When a user taps on a row of table view. It reveals the delete button.
2. When delete button is visible and user taps on row. The cell returns to normal state.

As of now, I am able to reveal the delete button on `swipe left` and perform appropriate action. And Item-2 is default behavior.

So only thing left to be done is programmatically reveal the delete button.

I have tried the following:

1. `cell.setEditing(true, animated: true)` in `didSelectRow` but this does not seem to have any effect.
2. Setting tableview.setEditing to true makes red delete icons appear from left, and on tapping these, the button from right is revealed. But this is not what I want.

As mentioned earlier, button is revealed on swipe left. So I believe my following function are implemented correctly:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
```

Even tried implementing following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
```

But again no effect.

So is there a way to achieve the behavior I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually ended up using: [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell)